# Crystal compiler does not detect that object is not nil

Tags: crystal-lang

I have the following class :

```
class X
    property son, val
    def initialize(@val : Int32)
        @son = nil.as X?
    end

    def add(other : X?)
        unless other.nil?
            if @son.nil?
                @son = other
            else
                @son.add(other)
            end
        end
    end
end

x = X.new 5
x.add(nil)
x.add(X.new 3)
```

But when I try to `build` I get

```
Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

In nil-test.cr:12:22

 12 | @son.add(other)
           ^------
Error: undefined method 'include' for Nil (compile-time type is (X | Nil))
```

According to [the manual](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/if_var_nil.html), this is exactly the kind of situation where the compiler should recognize that `@son` cannot be `nil` in the `else` branch, yet it apparently fails to do so.

What am I doing wrong ?

Note : using `@son.not_nil!.add(other)` works, I'm just asking why the compiler can't do without.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That only works for local variables, not instance variables - since the instance variables may be mutated by another fiber between the condition and you accessing the variable. See [this section](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/if_var.html) (under "Limitations") in the Crystal docs.

You can do it like this, assigning the instance variable to a local variable that will not change out from under you:

```
def add(other : X?)
  unless other.nil?
    if s = @son
      s.add(other)
    else
      @son = other
    end
  end
end
```